# PHP: connect with external mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

I want to connect with external database using `PHP`. But, it gives this error

```
Warning: mysql_connect(): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'SERVER_IP_ADDRESS' (110) in /home/<username>/public_html/index.php on line 7
Can't connect to MySQL server on 'SERVER_IP_ADDRESS' (110)
```

Here is my code.

```
define("_CONFIG_DB_HOST", "SERVER_IP_ADDRESS");  /* database host name */
define("_CONFIG_DB_NAME", "DATABASE_NAME");    /* database name */
define("_CONFIG_DB_USER", "DATABASE_USERNAME");    /* database username */
define("_CONFIG_DB_PASS", "DATABASE_PASSWORD");    /* database password */


$con = mysql_connect(_CONFIG_DB_HOST,_CONFIG_DB_USER,_CONFIG_DB_PASS) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db(_CONFIG_DB_NAME,$con) or die(mysql_error());
```

I've also added entry for `Remote Database Access Hosts` in Host Server

Please guide me if I'm doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `DATABASE_USERNAME` has access from *you host* (the machine running this script) has access to `DATABASE_NAME` on `SERVER_IP_ADDRESS`.

When you grant access on database to use you would use `USERNAME@HOST` form. Here the `HOST` means the host where this `USERNAME` would be connecting from. Usually we keep it *localhost*. becasue we want to connect by a user who is in localhost according to mysql server. But your local host is not mysql servers localhost. That's why that host part needs to be changed.

Comment: Thank you for your time. Can you please tell me; where to grant access from? I've already added my hostname to 'Remote Database Access Hosts' list.
e.g: I want to connect Host A database From Host B. I allowed Host B in Host A to access database of Host A.

Comment: There is query for that. `Grant user@host on ...`.  See [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html)